# How prevent duplicate records in appmaker?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have tried the code below but encountered some errors:

```
var query = app.models.Hardware.newQuery();
query.filters.HardwareId._equals = record.HardwareId;
if (query.run().length) {
    throw 'Hardware ID "' + record.HardwareId + '" is in use.';
}
```

Errors encountered below:

> Saving records: (Error) : Cannot set property "_equals" of undefined to "undefined".
>   at models.CheckpointBooking.onAfterCreateEvent:2
>   at saveChanges (ChkPointEditPgAction:54:21)
>   at ChkPointPageFm.Form1.Form1Footer.Form1SubmitButton.onClick:1:1

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please provide Full function call here? record can be coming blank. Please share table design also if possible

Comment: The other thing I noticed is that your error line 2 refers to your model onAfterCreate event, I would suggest putting your code to check for duplicate records in the onBeforeCreate event because otherwise your duplicate record may still get created.

Comment: Hi Darpan/Markus, I created a form -> key-in the RegistrationDate and StaffName is assigned to the user creating the form -> then Saved the form. I have placed the code in the onBeforeCreate. In this code I would like to check on the duplication of the StaffName. After placing the code in onBeforeCreate, there is no error but the form get created without prompting duplication. The field RegistrationDate is a Date field, the StaffName is a String field with Unique checkbox checked.